Cann't pass the code verification while generate the deploy data with getDeployTransaction and sign with metamask
I deployed a contract with hardhat and metamask in following steps:
0, The solidity version is 0.8.24 (hardhat.config.ts)
1, Generate the deployment data with getDeployTransaction
2, Construct the transaction
3, Sign and send the transaction with metamask
4, Flat the code and verify in blockchain explorer, and failed.
Bytecode (what we are looking for)
60806040523480156200001157600080fd5b50....
(My bytecode:)
608060405234801562000010575f80fd5b50....
The head of the bytecode is different, so I think maybe the getDeployTransaction has some issue, anyone have ever met the same scene please?

Check that you are verifying with same optimization settings. By default hardhat.config has optimization disabled
